# difficulty renaming batch of files with PowerShell without losing extension

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use `PowerShell` to rename a folder containing thousands of images. I want to add both a prefix and a suffix, but this is proving more difficult than I bargained for. I don't understand PowerShell at all... and have dug around for help, and ended up with mixed results.

The best I've found was the example here: [Renaming Files with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094615/renaming-files-with-powershell)

Which yields ...

> Dir -recurse | Sort {$*.FullName.Length} -Desc | Rename-Item {$*.Name -replace ' ','_'}

Now, I'm not wanting to *replace* anything, so I tried to just

> Dir -recurse | Sort {$*.FullName.Length} -Desc | Rename-Item { "pre-" + $*.Name + "-suff" }

That gave me an error though, and I'm not quite sure how to interpret it;

```
Rename-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument ' "pre-" + $_.Name + "-suff" '.
At line:1 char:50
+ ... _.FullName.Length} -Desc | Rename-Item { "pre-" + $_.Name + "-suff" }
+                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Rename-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

I quite literally have no idea what this is trying to say. I've dug around deeper, and found this tutorial: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/11/22/use-powershell-to-rename-files-in-bulk.aspx

And it has some slightly different commands, so I tried to plug that in with...

> Get-ChildItem -Filter "*current*" -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { "pre-" + $_.name + "-suffix" }

And I get no error, but nothing seems to happen, either. This is proving to be very frustrating, as I keep searching for answers but every page I turn up is nebulous at best. Is there a simpler way to accomplish this? I'm wanting to append the prefix and suffix without affecting the file extension.

I did find something a bit closer to what I needed at: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25144.powershell-bulk-renaming-file-names.aspx

And it suggested this script,

> Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $*.Extension -eq ".jpg" -or $*.Extension -eq ".png"} | rename-item -newname {"CL - " + $_.Name}

Which I changed to ...

> Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $*.Extension -eq ".jpg" -or $*.Extension -eq ".png"} | rename-item -newname {"prefix-" + $_.Name + "-suffix" }

And that at least did something to the files, but now the suffix is appended **after** the extension, which is obviously not what I'm going for.

Comment: Change `{"prefix-" + $_.Name + "-suffix"}` to `{"prefix-$($_.BaseName)-suffix$($_.Extension)"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are almost there :)

```
Get-ChildItem -Include *.jpg,*.png -Recurse | 
  Rename-Item -NewName { 'Prefix' + $_.BaseName + 'Suffix' +  $_.Extension } -WhatIf
```

Notice the `-whatif` at the end...this switch simulates command execution...Run the code first see the `whatif` output and if you are satisfied with the results then run the same command above without the `-whatif` to execute.

the `$_.name` includes the filename with the extension which is why you are getting the filenames with the suffix appended to the extension.

`Get-Childitem | fl *` will show you what properties you can work with.

Comment: +1 on explaining the issues and providing steps but any specific reason you are using + to concatenate strings? *(and you've forgotten the suffix in the string)*

Comment: @Lieven Keersmaekers - personally i too use the double quotation marks to concatenate strings but in this example i felt the use of `+` better demonstrated the addition of suffix and prefix to the basename....yup i did forget the suffix, thanks for catching that :)...

Comment: **You are a god among insects**! Thank you so much, this is amazing! This is _exactly_ what I needed!