# Embedding file paths to names

Tags: python, powershell, file-rename, batch-rename

I have a similar issue: I want to batch-rename files like:

```
c:>/folder/path_a/to/my_first_file.txt
c:>/folder/path_b/to/my_2_nd_file.txt
c:>/folder/path_c/to/my_bla_bla.txt
c:>/folder/path_d/to/pippo.txt
c:>/folder/path_d/to/pluto.txt
c:>/folder/path_d/to/my_bla_bla.txt
```

and I'd would rename them as:

```
c:>/folder/path_a-to_my_first_file.txt
c:>/folder/path_b-to-my_2_nd_file.txt
c:>/folder/path_c-to-my_bla_bla.txt
c:>/folder/path_d-to-pippo.txt
c:>/folder/path_d-to-pluto.txt
c:>/folder/path_d-to-my_bla_bla.txt
```

'embedding' part of the path to the filename

Can someone help me (I'm using Windows)?

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094615/renaming-files-with-powershell) but I don't know how to tell PS 'grab only subdirectorys name'

EDIT:
On python I'll have done sometng like this (sorry if code doesn't work but here I havn't python):

```
for dirname, _, fnames in os.walk('.'):
    first=dirname.replace('\','-')
    for fname in fnames:
        name="{}-{}".format(first,fname)
        os.rename("{}\{}".format(dirname,fname),"{}"name)

for for dirname,_,fname in os.walk('.'):
    os.remove(dirname)
```

================= Update ===================

As dealing with powershell was becaming a time-consuming issue, i put my data on a usb drive and used the following python script on another machine to do the job: (the script also changes the filename to remove an previous '.c' extention that was enbedded in flenames)

```
from os import rename, walk, chdir
EXT = '.c'
PATH = 'folder'    

chdir(PATH)
for cart, _, files in walk("."):
        for i in files:
                if os.path.isfile("{}/{}".format(cart,i)):
                        if EXT in i:
                                nn = i.replace(EXT,'') #removes inner extension
                                rename('{}/{}'.format(cart,i),'{}-{}'.format(cart,nn)) #changes the path
```

Comment: What do you do about the folders where they were? How do you decide where the root is? This should be fairly easy to do with some string manipulation. What have you tried?

Comment: My intention is to delete all the sub-folders and keep all in ./folder/. I'm not very handy on windows's command line (and unfortunatly I'm not on a privileged machine where I can install python onto) I know it's a matter of string manipulation but I have really no Idea on how to 'get' the right names on PS

Comment: Are all the folders at the same nesting level (ie. 3 folders deep)?

Comment: yes, those are all at the same depth

Comment: "grab only subdirectory's name" in PowerShell - `Split-Path "/path/to/file/filename.ext" -Parent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flattening/collapsing a directory tree isn't just renaming but moving files and afterwards deleting (empty) dirs.

```
## Q:\Test\2017\09\27\SO_46452350.ps1
$Base = 'C:\folder\'
Set-Location $Base
Get-ChildItem -Dir | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -File -Recurse |
        Move-Item -Destination {Join-Path $Base ($_.FullName.Replace($Base,'').Replace('\','_'))} 
    $_ | Remove-Item -Recurse
}
```

Sample tree:

```
> tree /F
C:.
└───folder
    ├───path_a
    │   └───to
    │           my_first_file.txt
    │
    ├───path_b
    │   └───to
    │           my_2_nd_file.txt
    │
    ├───path_c
    │   └───to
    │           my_bla_bla.txt
    │
    └───path_d
        └───to
                my_bla_bla.txt
                pippo.txt
                pluto.txt
```

After running script:

```
> tree /F
C:.
│
└───folder
        path_a_to_my_first_file.txt
        path_b_to_my_2_nd_file.txt
        path_c_to_my_bla_bla.txt
        path_d_to_my_bla_bla.txt
        path_d_to_pippo.txt
        path_d_to_pluto.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! (But I tryed it after having done all the stuff copying data on a thumb drive and working with them on a machine with python installed. Using PS was becaming too much time consuming)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
   $root = "c:>/folder/"
   $paths = "c:>/folder/path_a/to/my_first_file.txt",`
    "c:>/folder/path_b/to/my_2_nd_file.txt",`
    "c:>/folder/path_c/to/my_bla_bla.txt",`
    "c:>/folder/path_d/to/pippo.txt",`
    "c:>/folder/path_d/to/pluto.txt",`
    "c:>/folder/path_d/to/my_bla_bla.txt"

    function update-paths
    {

        params(
            string[] $paths
        )


        $paths | foreach {

            $path = $_.substring($root.Length,$_.Length-$root.Length)


            Write-Output ($root + ($path.replace("/","-")))

        }

    }

    update-paths -paths $paths

c:>/folder/path_a-to-my_first_file.txt
c:>/folder/path_b-to-my_2_nd_file.txt
c:>/folder/path_c-to-my_bla_bla.txt
c:>/folder/path_d-to-pippo.txt
c:>/folder/path_d-to-pluto.txt
c:>/folder/path_d-to-my_bla_bla.txt
```